# Send received data from API GET request to database using Laravel on the back-end

Tags: ajax, reactjs, laravel, redux, fetch

I am making a React-redux app that when you click a button a GET request is sent to retrieve data from an API. I have this set-up but I am now having trouble sending this data asynchronously to my database using Laravel and the fetch.api. Can anybody see what is wrong with my code?

//HTML

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

//web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

//api.php

```
Route::post('/', 'PostsController@store');
```

//posts controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post();

    $post->id = $request->('imdbID');
    $post->title = $request->('Title');
    $post->year = $request->('Year');
    $post->type = $request->('Type');
    $post->URL = $request->('Poster');

    $post save();

    return view('welcome');
}
```

//store.js

```
const persistedState = loadstate();
const store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState, 
applyMiddleware(...middleware));

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('state updated');
    console.log(store.getState());
    saveState(store.getState());
});
```

//actions.js

```
export const saveState = (state) => {
try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    fetch('/api', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    Headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    },
    body: { serializedState }
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => console.log(data));
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

}

I get the following errors;

app.js:77556 POST http://apijob.test/api 500 (Internal Server Error),

apijob.test/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Try this man `dd($request->all())` and watch how are you receiving the data in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm sorry but I'm new to Laravel and am unsure where I need to put this code.

Comment: In your controller

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Comment: I've made progress but not yet solved it. Please see the updated version.

Comment: did you forget `->` in `$post save();`

Comment: well spotted, I've added it but it still doesn't work sadly

Comment: Can you show me the error?

Comment: not sure how to send a picture on here but I will update my original post

Comment: include this in your header please  `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: I included it but it made no difference